# Using Select Scope_Identity() in a stored procedure without an output variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, scope-identity

I am trying to utilize a vendors stored procedure that I cannot change. In C# I need the `Scope_Identity` value. If I could I would set `@ID` as an output variable. Running the procedure in SQL Developer does return the proper ID.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTest]
    (@CountryName nvarchar(20))
AS
    DECLARE @ID int
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[CountryImages]([CountryName] )
    VALUES (@CountryName );

    SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    IF @ID > 0 
    BEGIN 
        RETURN @ID
    END
GO
```

I've tried this, but null is returned.

C#

```
....  
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryName", "abc");                   
conn.Open();   

var ID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT @ID` instead of `RETURN`. Is there any reason that `@ID > 0` would not be true, why do you need the `IF`? And what happens if you decide to restart your Identity column from negative numbers

Comment: @Charlieface "I am trying to utilize a vendors stored procedure that I can not change."